# SQL Server database consistency errors in database - how to repair

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a SQL Server database (Microsoft Dynamics AX), I just run `DBCC CHECKDB` in order to check the integrity.

After a few minutes I got at the end of the results the following:

```
CHECKDB found 0 allocation errors and 4 consistency errors in database 'AXPROD'.
repair_rebuild is the minimum repair level for the errors found by DBCC CHECKDB (AXPROD).
DBCC execution completed. If DBCC printed error messages, contact your system administrator.
```

Since I got 4 consistency errors I would like to know if there is a way to fix this, or a way to get a more detailed information about this errors.

Thanks

Comment: Question belongs on [dba.se]

Answer (score 0):

To run a DB repair, you'll have to first put the database into single user mode. There are 3 types of repairs you can do. Hopefully you just need to go through #1 or #2 below. The good news - based on your specific error message, it appears you won't be facing data loss since it just recommends the REPAIR_REBUILD.

1. `DBCC CHECKDB REPAIR_FAST` - Performs quick repairs without data loss
2. `DBCC CHECKDB REPAIR_REBUILD` - Everything in REPAIR_FAST plus more time-consuming repairs like rebuilding indexes
3. `DBCC CHECKDB REPAIR_ALLOW_DATA_LOSS` - Everything in REPAIR_REBUILD, but additional structural fixes that could result in data loss.

See: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa258278%28v=sql.80%29.aspx

Comment: Jason is there a way to get a more detailed information about this errors? Like a report or something?

Comment: There is a KB article (http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2015748) on how to do more research about how a consistency error may have occurred so perhaps you can trace the root cause. Beyond that, I'm not aware of a specific way to get the list of errors. If it were me, I'd start with REPAIR_FAST even though it says REPAIR_REBUILD, just in case that works for you.

Answer (score -2):

If you have valid backup then restoring from backup is the best solution to fix the error.

As suggested REPAIR_REBUILD is the minimum repair level for fixing the error, and might work but it is not guaranteed to fix the corruption. If that happens restoring from valid backup would be good choice.

Before restoring from valid backup you must need to run restore verifyonly on the backup that you are trying to restore from. It is the best method to check whether your backup is consistence or not.